# Multiple image upload error in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm to trying to upload multiple images in PHP CodeIgniter but it is displaying an error message as follows

> Error  Message: Illegal offset type in isset or empty
>   Filename: libraries/Upload.php
>   Line Number: 148
>   You did not select a file to upload.

My view file

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Upload Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    if(isset($error))
    {
     echo $error;
    }
    ?>

    <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
    <input type="file" name="userfile1" size="20" />

    <br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="upload" />

    </form>



    <?php 

    if(isset($upload_data))
    {
        echo "<ul>";

    foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):

    echo"<li>";

     echo $item . $value;

     echo" </li>";

     endforeach;

    echo "</ul>";
    }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

My controller file

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '10000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $fname= array('f1' => 'userfile','f2'=>'userfile' );

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($fname))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Please help me out to get my problem solved.

Comment: i have try to re edite my question but it is not post complited so understand may question and help me

Comment: You have to loop through $_FILES to do multiple uploads in CodeIgniter

Comment: mins how i perform that

Comment: pleace give me solution  i can not understand

Answer (score 2):

So, in order to do multiple uploads in the same request, you change the way CodeIgniter sees the incoming uploaded files with something similar to this:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '10000';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';

$this->load->library('upload');

$errors = [];
$files = $_FILES;
$upload_count = count( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] );
for( $i = 0; $i < $upload_count; $i++ )
{
    $_FILES['userfile'] = [
        'name'     => $files['userfile']['name'][$i],
        'type'     => $files['userfile']['type'][$i],
        'tmp_name' => $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i],
        'error'    => $files['userfile']['error'][$i],
        'size'     => $files['userfile']['size'][$i]
    ];

    $this->upload->initialize( $config );

    // Use upload library for file validation
    if( $this->upload->do_upload() )
    {
        // Upload was successful, do something ...
    }
    else
    {
        // Error: Upload Failed
        $errors[] = $this->upload->display_errors('','');
    }
}
```

This also means you change the names of your file inputs in the HTML to userfile[].